# Issue with iron-ajax request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, polymer-1.0

I have the following Web API method:

```
[Route("api/ConfAccount/ByToken")]
    public conf_account GetByToken(string token)
    {
        conf_accountDAO dao = new conf_accountDAO();
        try
        {
            string tokenJson = Crypto.DecryptStringAES(token, "S1gn2s2f3!");
            if (tokenJson != null)
            {
                Token myToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(tokenJson) as Token;
                var obj = dao.GetObjectByUser(myToken.name);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    return obj as conf_account;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried to make a request from a Polymer web application, I have an element that call this method but I don't find a way to configure correctly the iron-ajax object to call this method:

### Element

```
<dom-module id="my-welcome">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
        .div-general{
            @apply(--layout-horizontal);
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: table-cell;
        }
        .span-center-middle{
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
    <iron-ajax
        verbose
        url="http://192.168.0.16/SignaSafePro/api/ConfAccount/ByToken?"
        method='GET'
        params = '{{token}}'
        headers='{"Accept": "application/json"}'
        handle-as="json"
        content-type="application/json"
        on-response="handleResponse"
        debounce-duration="300"
        id='ajaxWelcomeElement'>
    </iron-ajax>
    <iron-localstorage name="my-signasafe-storage" id="localStorage_id" auto-save-disabled useRaw></iron-localstorage>
    <div class="div-general">
        <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" id="icon_account"></paper-icon-button>
        <span class="span-center-middle">{{welcome_text}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-welcome',
        properties: {
            conf_account: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true
            },
            welcome_text:{
                type: String,
                notify: true
            },
            token:{
                type: String,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            var localstorage = this.$$('#localStorage_id');
            localstorage.reload();
            var tokenAux = localstorage.value;
            this.token = tokenAux;
            var obj = this.$$('#ajaxWelcomeElement');
            if(this.token != null){
                obj.generateRequest();
            }else{
                this.welcome_text = 'Welcome Guest';
            }
        },
        handleResponse: function(request){
            var result = request.detail.response;
            if(result.ResultObject != null){
                this.conf_account = result.ResultObject;
                if(this.conf_account != null){
                    this.welcome_text = 'Welcome ' + this.conf_account.conf_account_name;
                }else{
                    this.welcome_text = 'Welcome Guest';
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting the Url Request in the console:

> http://192.168.0.16/SignaSafePro/api/ConfAccount/ByToken?&0=E&1=A&2=A&3=A&4=A&5=C&6=0&7=q&8=c&9=0&10=o&11=C&12=h&13=6&14=U&15=H&16=E&17=3&18=V&19=z&20=o&21=v&22=s&23=k&24=T&25=i&26=m&27=5&28=y&29=r&30=p&31=N&32=Z&33=v&34=Z&35=h&36=j&37=z&38=9&39=Y&40=v&41=O&42=S&43=p&44=d&45=q&46=r&47=H&48=w&49=l&50=D&51=m&52=3&53=o&54=G&55=0&56=a&57=A&58=K&59=y&60=R&61=R&62=v&63=q&64=F&65=B&66=m&67=4&68=v&69=S&70=P&71=T&72=P&73=9&74=B&75=P&76=R&77=C&78=7&79=R&80=s&81=m&82=X&83=M&84=X&85=C&86=j&87=U&88=X&89=u&90=f&91=o&92=s&93=8&94=i&95=C&96=2&97=z&98=C&99=o&100=y&101=c&102=B&103=0&104=1&105=O&106=h&107=B&108=J&109=n&110=L&111=L&112=2&113=B&114=7&115=J&116=O&117=q&118=Q&119=i&120=S&121=F&122=L&123=V&124=6&125=1&126=6&127=I&128=0&129=d&130=H&131=f&132=u&133=X&134=%2F&135=R&136=6&137=c&138=O&139=r&140=B&141=N&142=X&143=r&144=v&145=T&146=b&147=g&148=O&149=f&150=K&151=K&152=%2B&153=N&154=2&155=k&156=e&157=q&158=0&159=2&160=y&161=3&162=X&163=9&164=a&165=Z&166=S&167=n&168=A&169=R&170=U&171=f&172=x&173=G&174=Z&175=%2F&176=n&177=p&178=1&179=d&180=R&181=%2B&182=X&183=b&184=W&185=8&186=m&187=y&188=y&189=y&190=e&191=8&192=h&193=D&194=y&195=g&196=P&197=H&198=g&199=m&200=W&201=d&202=P&203=y&204=Y&205=H&206=j&207=0&208=z&209=T&210=b&211=8&212=U&213=b&214=9&215=Q&216=b&217=W&218=e&219=2&220=E&221=K&222=c&223=l&224=E&225=k&226=f&227=p&228=4&229=k&230=9&231=f&232=E&233=Z&234=o&235=a&236=2&237=c&238=n&239=I&240=D&241=Z&242=X&243=g&244=T&245=f&246=y&247=r&248=X&249=Q&250=B&251=Z&252=%2B&253=1&254=J&255=%2F&256=y&257=l&258=c&259=b&260=9&261=w&262=%3D&263=%3D

I don't know why the url get that way because the url suppose to be:

> GET api/ConfAccount/ByToken?token={token}

Please I really appreciate any help on this.

### Note:

The error that I'm getting is the Error: 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the iron-ajax element in this way:

```
<iron-ajax
        verbose
        url="http://192.168.0.16/SignaSafePro/api/ConfAccount/ByToken?token={{token}}"
        method='GET'
        handle-as = "json"
        content-type = 'application/json'
        on-response="handleResponse"
        debounce-duration="300"
        id='ajaxWelcomeElement'>
    </iron-ajax>
```

Thanks